# How to make a list with all possible words in tree in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tree, cpu-word

I have

```hs
t1 = Node 'a' (Node 'c' (Node 'f' Empty Empty)
 (Node 'd' Empty Empty))                     
 (Node 'b' Empty                            
 (Node 'e' Empty Empty))                    

data BTree = Empty | Node Char BTree BTree
```

The function I need to make is `genWords :: BTree -> [String]`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
genWords :: BTree -> [String]
genWords Empty = []
genWords (Node ch Empty Empty) = [ch]
genWords (Node ch left right) = map (ch:) (genWords left ++ genWords right)
```

I know my mistake is that I take chars and my function needs to return a list of strings, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Exactly what is the expected output here?

Comment: @Chi - isn't returning a list with empty string a bit redundant? I mean, I guess it depends if you want the output list to contain "" representing dead ends of the tree, but I don't think it's required (it would depend on the use case)

Comment: @ThomasCook Indeed, it depends on the wanted output. Perhaps the OP does not want the output I had in mind when I wrote the comment above. It also depends on whether you want the list of all root-to-leaf paths, or the list of root-to-any-node paths.

Comment: Actually, depending on the output you want, your code looks fine except it should probably return `[[ch]]` in the second equation (a list of one string, that being a single character long).

Comment: it should return ["acf", "acd","cf", "cd", "f", "d","abe", "be", "e"]

Comment: Should it return that? Or should it return all possible strings found by getting all possible combinations of the chars in the tree?

Comment: it should return all possible words that you can find in the tree

Comment: So, your example return list should contain:

"df", "de", "dc" and several other "words" no?

Comment: Your underlying data structure is a `BTree`, but the data type you are implementing with it is very similar to a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (the difference being, you are assuming every node represents a word, rather than tagging nodes as possible end-of-word markers or "just" letters in the middle of other words).

Answer (score 0):

`ch` is a `Char`. `[ch]` is a `String`. You probably want `[[ch]]` which is a list of strings (`[String]`).

More in detail, `[[ch]]` is a list containing exactly one string, that string being `[ch]`, which is made of the single character `ch`.

```
genWords :: BTree -> [String]
genWords Empty = []
genWords (Node ch Empty Empty) = [[ch]]
genWords (Node ch left right) = map (ch:) (genWords left ++ genWords right)
```

If you want the suffixes as well, try instead

```
genWords :: BTree -> [String]
genWords Empty = []
genWords (Node ch Empty Empty) = [[ch]]
genWords (Node ch left right) = map (ch:) subPaths ++ subPaths
   where subPaths = genWords left ++ genWords right
```

Comment: yeah, this returns ["acf","acd","abe"] but is should return it should return ["acf", "acd","cf", "cd", "f", "d","abe", "be", "e"]

Comment: @Dontor - I think you don't quite know what you want your function to return. Your example return list does not contain every combination of the chars in the tree does it?

Comment: What abouut "de"? I can find that as a "word" in your tree.. I can also find several others that aren't in your list

Comment: @ThomasCook I guess the OP wants the paths (any-internal-node)-to-(any-leaf).

Comment: `possibleStrings :: Int -> Int -> Int
possibleStrings len charCount
  | len == 1 = charCount
  | otherwise = foldl (*) start [(start + 1)..charCount] + possibleStrings (len - 1) charCount where
    start = charCount - (len - 1)`

The above will work out all possible combinations of the chars into words if I understand correctly. So, given 6 chars in the tree, there are 1956 possible words

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but in case someone lands here, I think this is the solution the asker is looking for:

```
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
  deriving Show

genWords :: BTree Char -> [String]
genWords Empty = []
genWords bTree@(Node v left right) = genRootWords bTree ++ genWords left ++ genWords right
  where genRootWords :: BTree Char -> [String]
        genRootWords Empty = []
        genRootWords (Node v Empty Empty) = [[v]]
        genRootWords (Node v left right)  = map (v:) (genRootWords left ++ genRootWords right)
```